# Get GPS co-ordinates into a PDF document on the press of a button

Tags: java, android, ios, pdf, gps

I am trying to figure out something for a friend and need some help.

My friend works with a volunteer group tracking mosquito migration to try and track the spread of malaria.  They use a PDF template to enter all of the data and currently manually enter GPS data onto it **IF** they have a GPS.

They would like to automate this and at the click of a button in the form they would like the GPS information 'grabbed' from the devices GPS at the spot they find the mosquito and entered into the PDF.  This would mean that the data would be consistent and more useful.

I have tried looking up using code with PDF but hit a brick wall.  I have created a form in Java with lots of drop down boxes and buttons to do the work of the PDF form but as this is most likely to be used on Android and iOS platforms I will need to learn them and re-code for those platforms.

Therefore does anyone know how to use code in a PDF form to do this or is it better to go down the Java/android/iOS coding route?

If I am to go the Android route what backend would everyone suggest?  an SQLite DB running in the background maybe?

Comment: If you require it in the file itself, an annotation may not be too bad.  If you just need a list of files and locations, then the sqlite db may work-  one table with lat, long, and filename.  But I'd question the need for pdf at all here-  its basically a form, right?  Remaking the form in Android and saving the data to an sqlite db will probably be a better experience, and almost certainly be easier to maintain if new features are needed.

Comment: Thanks Gabe, I thought as much, will be fun learning java for android anyhow!